# Is anyone else having problems with ClaimID?

Tags: discussion, openid, login

I can't log in. I get to the ClaimID login form, put in the details, submit the form and, although the browser status bar shows the right kind of activity, the form just reappears, no error message or anything.

I'm trying to move to Google's OpenID, but all the Stackoverflow move/change OpenID solutions involve being able to log in first, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a new account and we can merge the new and old accounts.

Mail us via the link at the bottom of every page.

**Be sure to include the URLs (or numeric user IDs, same thing) of both accounts, please!**